# Proof of projection on $W$ along $W'$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and T be the projection on $W$ along $W'$, where $W$ and $W'$ are subspaces of $V$. Find an ordered basis $\beta$ for $V$ such that $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

My proof is:
By the definition of "direct sum",  let $\beta_W$={$w_1,\dots,w_k$} is a basis for $W$ then
$\beta_V$={$w_1,\dots,w_k,w_{k+1},\dots,w_n$} is a basis for $V$
and $\beta_{W'}$={$w_{k+1},\dots,w_n$} is a basis for $W'$.
By the definition of "projection on $W$ along $W'$",
$T(w_i)=w_i$ for $1\le i \le k$ and
$T(w_j)=0$ for $k+1 \le j \le n$.
Thus $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix with $k$ 1's and $(n-k)$ o's on the diagonal and the rest of entries are zero.

I want to check this is right or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof looks fine to me, but rather than describing $\beta_W,\,\beta_{W'}$ and $\beta_V$ in your way, I would say:

> Since $V=W\oplus W'$, if we take a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\}\ (k=\dim W)$ of $W$ and a basis $\{w_{k+1},\ldots,w_n\}$ of $W'$, then $\beta=\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ is a basis of $V$.

But what wording is good is just a matter of taste.